# memory efficient way of passing large objects in R

Tags: r, function, scope, global-variables, environment-variables

I have a function that needs to access a variable in its parent environment (scope from which the function is called).  The variable is large in terms of memory so I would prefer not to pass it to by value to the function being called.  Is there a standard way of doing this other than declaring the variable in the global scope?  For example:

```
g <- function (a, b) { #do stuff}

f <- function(x) {
    y <- 3 #but in my program y is very large
    g(x, y)
}
```

I would like to access y in `g()`.  So something like this:

```
g <- function (a) { a+y }

f <- function(x) {
    y <- 3 #but in my program y is very large
    g(x)
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? `y` won't be copied unless you change it.

Comment: Good question though.  I learned this after rewriting a bunch of code to do as you suggest and found no noticable speedup.

Comment: how would you check if the value has been copied or the variable is just pointing to that address in memory? i understand what you are saying but i'm just curious about how this would be done in R

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no advantage to "declaring the variable in the global scope" and it may not even be possible in R depending on what you mean by that. You certainly could use the second form. The action that causes duplicate or even triplicate copies of an object is assignment. You will need to describe in more detail what you are trying to illustrate by the code: `y <- 3`. That would not normally be needed inside a function that merely accessed an object named "y" that was located in an enclosing frame.

Storing variables in a declared environment will sometimes improve efficiency of access, but my understanding is that the efficiency is in terms of improved speed because a hash table is used. One accesses items in an environment in the same manner as one accesses list elements:

```
> evn <- new.env()
> evn$a <- rnorm(100000)
> ls(evn)
[1] "a"
> length(evn$a)
[1] 100000
```

The BigMemory project may offer facilities for this: 
http://www.bigmemory.org/ . 
It and [Lumley's biglm](http://cran.r-project.org/package=biglm) may help with the large dataset mentioned in the comments.

Comment: thank you this is very helpful. in particular what my function does is run a regression and the dataframe with about 30 mil rows is what `y` is in my case.  i am guessing `lm()` does not modify the data in any way so then passing it should be ok.

Comment: But it will create a vector of residuals and another of linear predictors that will be 30 mil in length. Sometimes people will gain performance by using lm.fit, but in other situations it may be needed to sample some fraction of your data. The `subset` function can do that nicely.